# Implement the Lead conversion using custom button

Tags: triggers, salesforce

I will need to create a Custom Button "convert lead" that will perform the same functionality as Standard Button "Convert" when the button is clicked.

What is the best approach to do it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very broad question. What exactly you need, what have you tried so far? Do you really need just a button that opens the conversion page or something more?

If you want to somehow recreate it with Apex... Core of the coded solution would be the [`Database.convertLead`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm) method. You don't pass to it whole leads (like to `Database.insert` for example) but instead just their IDs + bunch of control flags to make it do exactly what you need. Read up about [`LeadConvert`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm) object. And similarly you can get Account/Contact/Opportunity ID from the result object if it succeeded.

I don't think there's programmatic way to access field names & mappings defined by administrator for lead conversion. Maybe you'd need to store this info somehow (in helper object? [custom metadata](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)?). So then you'd query the field names from metadata, then query the lead fields and finally display table of fields & mappings to the user.